# Receipt event not firing on contract.methods web3

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have the following piece of code

```
    contract.methods.x(params).send({from: wallet, value: web3.utils.toWei(betAmount.toString(), 'ether')})
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber: any, receipt: any){
        console.log('receipt', receipt);
    })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt: any){
        console.log('receipt', receipt);
    })
```

Problem is the confirmation event is fired yet there is never a receipt event fired. even though the receipt is actually there in the confirmation aswel. Do you guys have any idea?

The receipt event actually gives this error:

```
ror: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
at Object.TransactionError (errors.js:87:1)
```

Yet the transaction was succesful

Comment: Hello,
I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you manage to resolve it? Thanks.